# Fit column B based on column A

Tags: excel

How fit column B based on column A?

Example:

```
Code   Description
V1         One
V7         Seven
V3         Three
```

If column 'Code'(A) is V1 then column (B)'Description' is One
If column 'Code' is V7 then column 'Description' is Seven

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In B2 (and fill down),

```
=CHOOSE(--RIGHT(A2), "one", "", "three", "", "", "", "seven", "", "")
```

[image]